# Gcloud functions deploy crash

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

Everytime I try to deploy a function I get an error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): expected string or bytes-like object
```

I uploaded the same code manually in a zip file and there were no problems.

This is the command:

```
gcloud functions deploy myfunction \
  --runtime python39 \
  --trigger-http \
  --entry-point main \
  --source . \
  --region europe-west1 \
  --project myproject \
  --env-vars-file env.json
```

With debug anbled:

```
DEBUG: expected string or bytes-like object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 987, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 807, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/functions/deploy.py", line 104, in Run
    return command_v2.Run(args, self.ReleaseTrack())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/functions/v2/deploy/command.py", line 1065, in Run
    _SetInvokerPermissions(args, function, is_new_function)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/functions/v2/deploy/command.py", line 866, in _SetInvokerPermissions
    service_ref_one_platform = resources.REGISTRY.ParseRelativeName(
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/resources.py", line 1082, in ParseRelativeName
    return parser.ParseRelativeName(
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/resources.py", line 203, in ParseRelativeName
    match = re.match(path_template, relative_name)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bundledpythonunix/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 191, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Which version of Gcloud CLI are you using? I can see the latest version is [Gcloud CLI 468.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#46800_2024-03-12). Can you upgrade your SDK to the latest version and try again? Can you please share the reproducible steps or the documentation you are referring to?

Comment: Google Cloud SDK 411.0.0
alpha 2022.12.05
beta 2022.12.05
bq 2.0.83
bundled-python3-unix 3.9.12
core 2022.12.05
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gsutil 5.17

Comment: I have tried deploying the simple `Hello World` function by following the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-http-python-1st-gen) with the latest version of [Gcloud CLI 468.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#46800_2024-03-12) and able to deploy successfully. As you stated your `Google Cloud SDK 411.0.0` can you try updating to the latest version and redeploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it seems like you are using the older version of `Google Cloud SDK 411.0.0`, which is causing the below error message:

> ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): expected string or bytes-like object

I have tried deploying the simple `Hello World` function by following the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-http-python-1st-gen) with the latest version of [`Gcloud CLI 468.0.0`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#46800_2024-03-12) and able to deploy successfully.

Try upgrading to the latest version of [`Google Cloud SDK 468.0.0`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#46800_2024-03-12) and redeploy. It should work as expected.